# How to navigate json objects in django templating language

Tags: json, django

If I pass in a json object from my view i.e. return render(request, 'development/index.html', {'data': data}), where data is {a:{"colA":12,"colB":13"},b:{"ColA":1","colB":2"}}, how can I populate a select in index.html with all the values in ColA?

Answer (score 0):

You should be populating selects with options using django forms, not in template.

But if you absolutely have to do it in template then you can loop through dict like this:

```
{% for item in data.iteritems %}
{{ item.colA }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you populate selects with options using django forms? Also, for the loop you mentioned, the json passed in is a string, do I need to parse it using some build in json method?. Sorry, am new to django / front end web dev in general, trying to build a basic UI passing in parts of pandas data frames that I have converted to json using DataFrame.to_json()

Comment: Just look at django forms (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and how to set options for fields with choices (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield). Also going through tutorial (takes 10 mins man!) is well worth the effort.